# How can I specify an author if I'm using nuget.exe CLI

Tags: c#, nuget

How can I specify an author if I'm using `nuget.exe` CLI?

> nuget pack some.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects

Is there any option like `-author`? I can't find any in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [the `properties` command](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference#pack) to pass in values for the replacement tokens. You will need to create a new token for authors becaues [with the exception of `$configuration$`, values in the project will be used in preference to any assigned to the same token on the command line and the default `$author$` token is pulled from `AssemblyCompany` in the project.](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuspec#replacement-tokens)

In the nuspec file

```
<authors>$CustomAuthor$</authors>
```

From the command line

```
nuget pack some.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -properties CustomAuthor="Scott Chamberlain"
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add author information into the configuration file like below

`<authors>JiaLei</authors>`

Comment: Nuget is a great sh...